# Delete and remplace the date icon from a Material ui textfield

Tags: reactjs, date, input, material-ui, icons

I need to delete and maybe replace the current date icon from a material ui date text field :

```
 <TextField
            id="dateDebut"
            margin="normal"
            type="date"
            format={"YYYY-MM-DD"}
            value={this.state.dateDebut}
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true
            }}
            defaultValue={moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
            InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true, className: 'inputt' }}
            className="input"
            onChange={e =>
              this.handleChangeDateDebut(e.target.value)
            }
 />
```

I have tried to used the 'endAdornment' property but it adds a nex icon and doesn't replace the current date icon.
I have to change the position of the new icon too. What's the property to change size and position of the new icon ?

Someone can help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how an icon could be present on this field, unless it's somehow set by CSS class, which is not shown.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s30bA.png

Comment: What version of material-ui do you use? It's not reproducible with the latest (5.3) material-ui: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputwithicon-material-demo-forked-e1t85?file=/demo.js).

Comment: As you can see on the sandbox, i want to replace and delete the 'DATE' Icon at the right

Comment: Any ideas ?????

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? codesanbox/stackblitz/codepen?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inputwithicon-material-demo-forked-e1t85?file=/demo.js

Comment: By chance I opened this on Windows with the Edge browser. It does show the icon. I usually work on macOS with Safari, but I checked with Edge on macOS, and it also displays the icon, but for instance Firefox does not. So, it is a browser-related issue. MUI must just be wrapping the regular `<input>`, and its rendering is browser-dependent. I don't think you can remove the icon as it is supplied by the browser and beyond control of mui or react. The only suggestion I have is to have `type="text"` instead of date, but then you have to add the calendar dropdown, etc. yourself.